# Video Player In Xamarin Forms Throws System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

Im making an app for iOS and android that offers the ability to watch video's. Im currently working on the iOS implementation but each time I dismiss the viewcontroller holding an AVPlayer or MPPlayer the app throws 'System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element'. I have no idea why this happens. Ill share some example code.

Renderer

```
    using AnimeViewer.iOS.CustomRenderers;
    using AnimeViewer.Views.Partials;
    using AVFoundation;
    using Foundation;
    using UIKit;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(VideoPlayer), typeof(VideoPlayerRenderer))]

    namespace AnimeViewer.iOS.CustomRenderers
    {
         public class VideoPlayerRenderer : ViewRenderer<VideoPlayer, UIView>
    {
        public VideoPlayer VideoPlayer { get; set; }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<VideoPlayer> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null) return;
            VideoPlayer = e.NewElement;
            SetNativeControl(new UIView {Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds});

            var player = new AVPlayer(new NSUrl(VideoPlayer.Source));
            var playerLayer = new AVPlayerLayer
            {
                Player = player,
                Frame = Control.Frame
            };
            Control.Layer.AddSublayer(playerLayer);
            player.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:partials="clr-namespace:AnimeViewer.Views.Partials;assembly=AnimeViewer"
             x:Class="AnimeViewer.Views.VideoPlayerPage">
    <partials:VideoPlayer x:Name="Player"
                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom renderer to call the video player, you can use a DependencyService:

```
public class VideoPLayer : IVideoPlayer
{
    public void Play(string path)
    {
        var _player = new AVPlayer(NSUrl.FromFilename(path));
        var _playerController = new AVPlayerViewController();
        _playerController.Player = _player;

        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        var vc = window.RootViewController;
        while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
        {
            vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
        }

        vc.PresentViewController(_playerController, true, null);
        _playerController.View.Frame = vc.View.Frame;
    }
}
```

To learn more about DependencyService you can access the following link: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

Comment: Thanks for the code, I had done it this way before too, without success. But for the purpose of showing you, I did it exactly with your code.

Look at what happens

1. I can click the episodes opening the video
https://puu.sh/t1XcQ/302e2a11f7.png
2. I can watch the video without any problems, its perfect!
https://puu.sh/t1Xft/0d35f62409.png
3. After clicking done in the left top corner, after about 3~ seconds this error pops up
https://puu.sh/t1Xh6/e2362bccbd.png

Comment: Are you sure that the path you're passing is correct? Maybe the file is not in a correct format?
Are you opening the video from a local resource or from an uri?

Comment: It might be happening because you're setting the SelectedItem before finishing the Tapped event, did you try not doing it at all to see if it works?

Comment: I think Its because Im setting it to null retriggering the event with a null value. I think I mightve made this mistake before, I feel so dumb.. Lets check

Comment: seems like that wasnt even the problem, since manually changing the selected item doesn't even call that event. Its getting thrown shortly after closing the viewcontroller with the done button. I have no idea why though.

Comment: I fixed the problem, thanks for the help. It was not relevant to the video playing code.

Comment: What was happening? Just for curiosity